# App Limited Region Availability : Google Play Billing Policy Violation

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, google-play-console, billing

We have an android application in which we upload the courses. These courses contain **Videos,PDFs and Audios**. Users can purchase whatever course they want and after purchasing they will have access for that particular course for 365 Days.

Recently our application was removed from India Play Store with following message :

**Status: Your app’s distribution on Google Play is limited to the United Kingdom, Indonesia, Russia, and the European Economic Area if you are compliant with our policies in those countries.**

Please Find Entire Message in the image below...
[image]

I went through this email and according to it we need to remove existing payment gateway which was Pay-U Money and need to implement Google Play In App Billing Library which charges 15% for each course sold by our app.Pay-U was charging only 4% for each transaction and Google Play is charging us **15% which is pretty big impact on the business margins** for us.

Basically google's play policy forced us to user google in app billing as only payment method in out android app.

1. I wanted to understand and ask if we are the only app/platform which got such restrictions or other apps also have got into same situation?
2. I also wanted to ask here that really our application is violating the google developer payment policy?
3. I went through other platforms like Netflix , Sony they still have other payment gateways implemented in their application.Is there any way to avoid such payment restrictions ?

note : we run business in India only !

Comment: QUestions about app store terms of use like this are off topic here.  This site is for programming questions only.

Comment: I understand that but android developers who develop code would be able to relate with this question - and such developers use stackoverflow a lot

Comment: I'm not saying it was stupid or malicious.  It's just not on topic here.  We don't allow quesitons that aren't programming or programming tools related, and we don't allow questions about app store terms of service.    This isn't a programming question, it's a business question.